# How to format a form GET request url

Tags: html, forms, search, text

How could i make a search input for a website where rather than a regular "?search=" it's just text with something appended, in this case ".htm"?

So for example argos works like this and if i type in "weight lifting" the url it makes is -

www.argos.co.uk/static/Search/searchTerm/weight+lifting.htm

I was trying the following however it does not work correctly -

```
<form name="search" method="get" style="margin-bottom:0%;" action="http://www.argos.co.uk/static/Search/searchTerm/"><input type="text" name="" maxlength="300">
    <input type="hidden" name="" value=".htm">
</form>
```

Is it possible to create a search input that could create the url i needed with a regular html form?

Comment: Not with HTML alone. You’d need JavaScript to do this (unless there’s something new I’m not aware of).

Comment: @zeddex, any feedback for the answer I provided?